# Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate.using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new to PHP and CakePHP. Finding problems while wiring my database using CakePhp.

Below is my app configuration.
I am on Bitnami WAMP stack 5.4.40-0
I am using CakePhp 3.0.4 to create a web mvc application

Entry for datasources in My app.php file

```
/**
 * Connection information used by the ORM to connect
 * to your application's datastores.
 * Drivers include Mysql Postgres Sqlite Sqlserver
 * See vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Driver for complete list
 */
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',
        'username' => 'test2',
        'password' => 'computer',
        'database' => 'jobs',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,

        /**
         * Set identifier quoting to true if you are using reserved words or
         * special characters in your table or column names. Enabling this
         * setting will result in queries built using the Query Builder having
         * identifiers quoted when creating SQL. It should be noted that this
         * decreases performance because each query needs to be traversed and
         * manipulated before being executed.
         */
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

        /**
         * During development, if using MySQL < 5.6, uncommenting the
         * following line could boost the speed at which schema metadata is
         * fetched from the database. It can also be set directly with the
         * mysql configuration directive 'innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'
         * which is the recommended value in production environments
         */
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ],
```

I could generate the basic boiler plate code using the bake command

But now when i run my application in localhost:8765/myapp

I get the following error

```
2015-07-01 14:31:22 Error: [RuntimeException] Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate.
```

Request URL: /myjobs

My code for controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Jobs Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\JobsTable $Jobs
 */
class MyJobsController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Jobs']
        ];
        $this->set('jobs', $this->paginate($this->Jobs));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['jobs']);
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Job id.
     * @return void
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $job = $this->Jobs->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Jobs']
        ]);
        $this->set('job', $job);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['job']);
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $job = $this->Jobs->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $job = $this->Jobs->patchEntity($job, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Jobs->save($job)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The job has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The job could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $jobs = $this->Jobs->Jobs->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('job', 'jobs'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['job']);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Job id.
     * @return void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $job = $this->Jobs->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $job = $this->Jobs->patchEntity($job, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Jobs->save($job)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The job has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The job could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $jobs = $this->Jobs->Jobs->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('job', 'jobs'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['job']);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Job id.
     * @return void Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $job = $this->Jobs->get($id);
        if ($this->Jobs->delete($job)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The job has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The job could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

Also would like to know where is the internal server located running in port 8765 located. ? I want to debug the resources on this server using eclipse.

Comment: Did you bake that controller, and then rename it from `Jobs` to `MyJobs`? What is `$this->Jobs` (i.e. check - is it an object or null)? `where is the internal server located running in port 8765 located` - that's [php's built-in webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), it's just running your code.

Comment: its a null...and the controller is renamed

Answer (score 9):

This error happens when you type the wrong url:

It should be one of

```
localhost:8765/my-app   
localhost:8765/myApp 
localhost:8765/my_app
```

but not: localhost:8765/myapp

Answer (score -1):

I guess it was some problem with my table structure.

Probably CakePHP looks for certain attributes in a table. 
Specially the auto increment attribute of the id which was a primary key.

I created my table structure according to the bookmarker table and it worked.

I had an enum field which is not mapped to objects through CakePHP. I guess enums are limitation with CakePHP.

Regards,

Saurav

Comment: This answer has no bearing on the question - the controller wasn't loading the model, hence the variable passed to paginate was `null` instead of the name of a model, or a query object.

Comment: yes but the model was not getting loaded because of some problem in the db structure

Comment: probably you are right...but i did not do any change to the controller class apart from renaming it...

Comment: The loadModel call is unnecessary/covered by conventions if the controller name matches the model name; thus renaming the controller file is directly responsible for it not working.  Its the reason my first question was whether the controller had been renamed. See the source of Controller.php, for more info.